# VBA Filter multiple ctiteria in sting type

Tags: string, excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to write a code for a autofilter, the aim is to filter around 10 criteria, each of them is a string such as `M1454` (in another word, as long as the data contain `M1454`) then it will be filtered). But I am having problem using array for the string criteria. Here is the code I used using exact criteria:

```
Sub AutoFilter()
    'Select the whole worksheet for filter'
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A:BB").Select

     'Set the condition for BType'
     Selection.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array( _
         "M1454H", "M1643D", "M1670D", "M1736A", "M1747B", "M1747C", _
         "M1766B", "M1796B", "M1796Z", "M1867A", "M1867B", "M1947B", _
         "M2617A", "M4886A"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

But if I change the criteria from `M1454H` to `*M1454*` then error shows up. Do anyone have any idea why this happen, thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to perform this sort of filter? That would almost certainly give you the correct syntax to use/modify.

Comment: The recording for "cotains" can only take max of 2 values and use Operator xlOr which can not be use for more than 2 values also. So basically there is no way (except for macro) you can filter out 4-5 criteria in "Contains" mode)

Comment: the code youre using seems ok. the problem here its impossible to do what you are trying to do. If you are using an array to filter values then it can only match against the entire string, you cannot use *half * of a word, or any type of regex

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help -- for example, if you physically require the `AutoFilter` method for some reason, this probably won't cut it.  But if you're simply looking for a way to find all the matching cells, this should work, and it will provide you a means to iterate over those cell ranges.

In the example, the dictionary stores the matching cell's address as `Key` values, and the matching cell's `.Row.Address` as `Item` values.

You can then iterate over the `Keys` or `Items` in the dictionary to work with those range/addresses.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFilteredRangeCells()

'REQUIRES REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT SCRIPTING RUNTIME LIBRARY

Dim rng As Range  '## The range you want to filter
Dim firstFound As Range '## to use with the .Find method
Dim fndRange As Range '## to use with the .Find method
Dim f As Long '## column # that is being filtered on
Dim filteredDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dictKey As Variant
Dim dictItem As Variant
Dim crit As Variant '## use this to iterate filterCriteria array

'## establish an array of values to filter, modify as needed ##'
Dim filterCriteria(1 To 3) As Variant 
    filterCriteria(1) = "*1414*"
    filterCriteria(2) = "*B*"
    filterCriteria(3) = "*Jo*"

    Set rng = Range("A1:B82") '## The range to search
    f = 1  '## Modify as needed, this will search the first column


    For Each crit In filterCriteria

        Set firstFound = Nothing 'clear out this variable
        Set firstFound = rng.Columns(1).Find(crit, After:=rng.Cells(f, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)    'find the first match

        'if any match is found, then find the rest
        If Not firstFound Is Nothing Then
            Set fndRange = firstFound
            Do
                Set fndRange = rng.Columns(f).FindNext(fndRange)
                'Duplicates are not allowed in a Dictionary:
                If Not filteredDict.Exists(fndRange.Address) Then
                    filteredDict.Add fndRange.Address, rng.Rows(fndRange.Row).Address
                End If
            Loop While Not fndRange.Address = firstFound.Address
        End If
    Next

    '## You can then iterate over the Keys, as needed:
    For Each dictKey In filteredDict.Keys
        Debug.Print dictKey & " -- "; filteredDict.Item(dictKey)
    Next

    Set filteredDict = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note:** This requires that you add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. If you cannot do this, then you can modify the code thusly, and it should still work:

```
Dim filteredDict as Object
Set filteredDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, David I did try to input the code, so it will give out the cordinates of the data I want in the immediate window right ? Not really what I am looking for since I need to acess the data to copy after that, but it is indeed interesting :)

Comment: Yes, the code I provided simply prints the information to the immediates window. I only am able to provide this basic example because you did not indicate what you need to do with the data once it has been filtered and collected.  If you would like to print the information on another sheet, in another workbook, etc., this should be easy to modify.